# Converting widechars to system ANSI encoding in Python

Tags: python, character-encoding, widechar

I am currently trying to make my screen reader work better with [Becky! Internet Mail](http://www.rimarts.co.jp/becky.htm). The problem which I am facing is related to the list view in there. This control is not Unicode aware but the items are custom drawn on screen so  when someone looks at it content of all fields regardless of encoding looks okay. When accessed via  MSAA or UIA however basic ANSI chars and mails encoded with the code page set for non Unicode programs have they text correct whereas mails encoded in Unicode do not. 
Samples of the text :

Zażółć gęślą jaźń

is represented by:

ZaĹĽĂłĹ‚Ä‡ gÄ™Ĺ›lÄ… jaĹşĹ„
In this case it is damaged CP1250 as per answer below.
However:
⚠️

is represented by:
âš ď¸Ź

⏰
is represented by:
âŹ°
and
高生旺
is represented by:
é«ç”źć—ş

I've just assumed that these strings  are damaged beyond repair, however when unicode beta support in windows 10 is enabled they are exposed correctly.

Is it possible to simulate this behavior in Python?

The solution needs to work in both Python 2 and 3.

At the moment I am simply replacing known combinations of these characters with their proper representations, but it is not very good solution, because lists containing replacements and characters to replace needs to be updated with each new discovered character.

Comment: ANSI is not a well-defined term in this context. What you have seems to be Windows code page 1250. You should probably read the [Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](/tags/character-encoding/info) for background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your utf-8 is decoded as cp1250.

What I did in python3 is this:

```
orig = "Zażółć gęślą jaźń"
wrong = "ZaĹĽĂłĹ‚Ä‡ gÄ™Ĺ›lÄ… jaĹşĹ„"

for enc in range(437, 1300):
    try:
        res = orig.encode().decode(f"cp{enc}")
        if res == wrong:
            print('FOUND', res, enc)
    except:
        pass
```

...and the result was the 1250 codepage.

So your solution shall be:

```
import sys

def restore(garbaged):
    # python 3
    if sys.version_info.major > 2:
        return garbaged.encode('cp1250').decode()
    # python 2
    else:
        # is it a string
        try:
            return garbaged.decode('utf-8').encode('cp1250')
        # or is it unicode
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            return garbaged.encode('cp1250')
```

**EDIT:**

The reason why `"高生旺"` can not be recovered from `é«ç”źć—ş`:

`"高生旺".encode('utf-8')` is `b'\xe9\xab\x98\xe7\x94\x9f\xe6\x97\xba'`.

The problem is the `\x98` part. In cp1250 there is no character set for that value. If you try this:

```
"高生旺".encode('utf-8').decode('cp1250')
```

You will get this error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 2: character maps to <undefined>`

The way to get `"é«ç”źć—ş"` is:

```
"高生旺".encode('utf-8').decode('cp1250', 'ignore')
```

But the `ignore` part is critical, it causes data loss:

`'é«ç”źć—ş'.encode('cp1250')` is `b'\xe9\xab\xe7\x94\x9f\xe6\x97\xba'`.

If you compare these two:

```
b'\xe9\xab\xe7\x94\x9f\xe6\x97\xba'
b'\xe9\xab\x98\xe7\x94\x9f\xe6\x97\xba'
```

you will see that the `\x98` character is missing so when you try to restore the original content, you will get a `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: invalid continuation byte`.

If you try this:

```
'é«ç”źć—ş'.encode('cp1250').decode('utf-8', 'backslashreplace')
```

The result will be `'\\xe9\\xab生旺'`. `\xe9\xab\x98` could be decoded to `高`, from `\xe9\xab` it is not possible.

Comment: It works when done in the interpreter, however when done in a plugin in the screen reader the orginal string is received as Unicode and it fails as follows:  File "encodings\utf_8.pyo", line 16, in decode
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 2-9: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @lukaszgo1 updated the code so it works now for unicode chars in python2 too

Comment: While it works  for the string from my original question it fails for others. I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: ```python
print(restore(u"test âš\xa0 âŹ°"))
```

results `test ⚠ ⏰` for me both in python 2 and 3

Comment: Okay it definitely works. I was trying in CMD hence the failures. Any chance of a solution for a Chinese string from my question? I'll wait a few days for an one, and if there is none will accept your answer.